# Rewrite many urls nginx php

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to rewrite many urls in nginx (same url) with different parameters but its not working..

For example, i have these rules on my **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** that's working fine:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        
        rewrite ^/inicio/?$ /inicio.php;
        rewrite ^/calendario/?$ /calendario.php;
        rewrite ^/assistir/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ /assistir.php?anime=$1&t=$2&ep=$3;
        rewrite ^/vizualizar/([\w-]+)/?$ /vizualizar.php?anime=$1;

        rewrite ^/categorias/?$ /categorias.php;
        rewrite ^/categorias/([\w-]+)/?$ /categorias.php?idioma=$1;
    }
```

However, if i try to rewrite more urls for the same file with others parameters, it don't work:

```
rewrite ^/categorias/([\w-]+)/?$ /categorias.php?idioma=$1;
rewrite ^/categorias/([\w-]+)/?$ /categorias.php?genero=$1;
rewrite ^/categorias/([\w-]+)/?$ /categorias.php?ano=$1;
```

Could someone help me to do that?

Also, there's way to rewrite a lot of urls without doing individual rewrite for each url?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Those three `rewrite` rules contain the same regular expression. What are you trying to do? The second and third rule can never be invoked.

Comment: @RichardSmith I wanted to rewrite these urls for this: /categorias/value where "value" is value of ?idioma or ?ano or ?genero. Maybe its not be possible? i need to do with: /categorias/idioma/value, /categorias/genero/value, etc?